# SQL Query for Group by and SUM

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum

I have 2 tables tblProjects & tblTasks

tblProjects has

```
ID,PName columns
```

tbltasks has

```
ID,PID,TaskDescription,Owner,Status
```

I am trying to write a query for getting a status of the projects which gives how many tasks are in open and close status for all projects

Output be like

```
PName|Open|Closed
```

I used some subqueries and Sum and Groupby but the output was not as expected.

Requesting experts to help.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Can you include the query which you have already tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
may be this one help

SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.PName,
       Open=SUM(CASE (t2.Status) WHEN 'open'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       Closed=SUM(CASE (t2.Status) WHEN 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM tblProjects t1
INNER JOIN tblTasks t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.PID
GROUP BY t1.ID,
         t1.PName
```

Comment: This is a blatant copy of my answer.  Duly downvoted.

Comment: dear its not mine not yours its just simple answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but you can try the following straightforward query which uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.PName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Status = 'open'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Open,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Status = 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Closed
FROM tblProjects t1
INNER JOIN tblTasks t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.PID
GROUP BY t1.ID,
         t1.PName
```

Comment: I was writing the same queries only thing i missed was case. Thanks for your Help guys. :)

Comment: thanks for down vote me its a cheap thing, dear its not mine not yours its just simple answer to the question